# Finding the maximum element of the array is a divisor of another element

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of non-zero integers of length N. Write a function that returns the maximum element of the array, which is a divisor of some other element of the same array. If this number is not present, then return `0`. I know how to solve in `O(n^2)`. Is it possible to do it faster?

Comment: I don't understand the requirements precisely. To my understanding, the result of `0` could occur for an empty input at best. For a nonemtpy input, the first element will be a divisor of itself, so the result will be the maximum of a non-empty set.

Comment: @Codor the question requires the number to be a divisor of _some other_ element of the same array. I find the requirements quite clear.

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks for the clarification, I misread that *other* part.

Comment: If two elements are the same, for example a [3] = a [11] = 7, does that count as "divisor of some other element"?

Comment: @Anton how big is the largest element in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that you are assuming that testing if integer A divides integer B can be completed in O(1). I guess you're also assuming that no pre-computation (e.g. building a [divisibility graph](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DivisibilityGraph/)) is allowed.

Since [integer factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) (for which no polynomial algorithm is known) is not an option, you can't do faster then O(n^2) (worst case).

For example, given the input {11,127, 16139} (all integers are primes, each integer squared is less than the next one), you can't avoid checking all pairs.

Comment: Your reasoning is right for the theoretical case where the integers are unbound. But if you consider it as a real problem where integers are bound (for instance, 32bit integers) and focus on the average case instead of the worst one, then it may turn into an interesting problem!

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing with your problem for a while and found a sometimes-better than brute-force solution.

It is based in to ideas:

- We can perform the search in an order such that bigger divisor candidates are tested first. That way we can terminate the search as soon as we find a divisor.
- One way to test if some candidate `divw` is a divisor for number `w`, is to calculate `r = floor(w / divw)` and then check that `r * divw == w`. The interesting thing, is that when it fails, we can calculate a top limit for the next divisor candidate of `w` as `topw = floor(w / (r + 1))`. So we can discard anything between `divw` and `topw`.

A sample for that second point: Imagine we are testing if `divw = 10` is a divisor of `w = 12`, we calculate `r = floor(12 / 10) = 1`, and `topw = floor(w / 2) = 6`. So, we don't need to check if numbers in the set between `7` and `9`, inclusive, are divisors for `12`.

In order to implement this algorithm I have used a heap to keep the numbers in the set using as key the next divisor candidate that has to be tested.

So...

1. Initialize the heap pushing every element which its predecessor as its bigger potential divisor.
2. Pop the first element from the heap (`w`) and check if the potential divisor candidate (`divw`) is actually a divisor.
3. If it is, return it as the biggest divisor
4. Calculate `topw` for `w`, `divw`; search the next element in the set `divw'` that is equal or lesser than `topw` (using binary-search); if found, push `w`,`divw'` again in the queue.
5. unless the queue is empty, goto `2`.

An implementation in Common Lisp is available [here](https://github.com/salva/simplering/blob/master/maxdiv/maxdiv.lisp)!

I guess calculating the theoretical computational cost for this algorithm would be challenging, specially for the average case, so I am not going to do it!

After running it a dozen times, it seems to behave better than the brute force approach when N is high and the numbers are dispersed (which means that the probability of one number being a divisor of other is low). On the other hand, brute-force seems to be faster when N is low or when the numbers are densely distributed in a small range (which means that the probability of a number being a divisor of other is high).

Answer (score 0):

I did it so

```
int f(int* a, int size)
{
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            if (a[i] > a[j] && a[i] % a[j] == 0 && a[j] > max)
                max = a[j];
    return max;
}
```